# Bounded second derivative bounds first at 1/2?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$, which is twice-differentiable and satisfies $f(0)=f(1)$. Suppose that $M>0$ is such that $|f''(x)|\leq M$ for all $0<x<1$. Prove that $|f'(1/2)|\leq M/4$.

My attempt is as follows:

$$0=f(1)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1/2}f''(t)\,dt+f'(1/2)\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow\left|\int_{0}^1f'(1/2)\,dx\right|=\left|\int_0^1\int_x^{1/2}f''(t)\,dt\,dx\right|$$
$$\Rightarrow\left|\int_{0}^1f'(1/2)\,dx\right|\leq\int_0^1\int_x^{1/2}|f''(t)|\,dt\,dx$$
Integrating on the left side and using a ML estimate on the right,
$$\Rightarrow|f'(1/2)|\leq\int_0^1M(1/2-x)\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow|f'(1/2)|\leq\int_0^{1/2}M(1/2-x)\,dx+\int_{1/2}^1M(1/2-x)\,dx\leq\int_{1/2}^1M(1/2-x)\,dx$$
since $\int_0^{1/2}M(1/2-x)\,dx$ is less than or equal to $0$. Using another ML estimate,
$$|f'(1/2)|\leq (M/2)(1/2)=M/4$$

My issue with this is that we do not know that $f'$ or $f''$ are integrable. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well $f'$ is differentiable, hence continuous, hence Riemann integrable. But you're right, we don't know $f''$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor's theorem (Lagrange remainder),

$$0 = f(0) = f(1/2) + f'(1/2)(-1/2) + (f''(c_x)/2)(1/2)^2,$$

$$0 = f(1) = f(1/2) + f'(1/2)(1/2) + (f''(d_x)/2)(1/2)^2.$$

Subtract to get

$$0 = 2f'(1/2)(-1/2) + (f''(c_x)/2)(1/2)^2 - (f''(d_x)/2)(1/2)^2.$$

Solve for $f'(1/2)$ and then estimate:

$$|f'(1/2)| \le (M/2)(1/2)^2 + (M/2)(1/2)^2 = M/4.$$

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks a lot.